# mysql query select case more then 1 table

Tags: mysql

i have problem with select case..

the tables

> 1. **template** (temp_id, temp_title, temp_applyto, temp_status, start_date, end_date)
>
>    > [where temp_applyto store int 1-individu, 2-branch, 3-dept and 4-position]
> 2. **individu** (applyto_id, applyto_individu, applyto_temp)
> 3. **branch** (applyto_id, applyto_branch, applyto_temp)
> 4. **dept** (applyto_id, applyto_dept, applyto_temp)
> 5. **position** (applyto_id, applyto_position, applyto_temp)
> 6. **staff** (id, name, branch, dept, position)

desc:

i want to check user if he's in table individu, branch, dept or position. if the **temp_applyto (table template)=1** then i want to check table **individu** if the user exist, if the **temp_applyto=2** then i want to check table **branch** if the user exist and same goes on.

the query so far:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN temp_applyto=1 
    THEN (SELECT applyto_temp FROM individu 
          WHERE applyto_individu=$user)
    WHEN temp_applyto=2 
    THEN (SELECT a.applyto_temp FROM branch a, staff b 
          WHERE >a.applyto_branch=b.branch AND b.id=$user) 
    WHEN temp_applyto=3 
    THEN (SELECT a.applyto_temp FROM dept a, staff b 
          WHERE >a.applyto_dept=b.dept AND b.id=$user) 
    WHEN temp_applyto=4 THEN (SELECT a.applyto_temp FROM position a, staff b 
          WHERE a.applyto_position=b.position AND b.id=$user) 
    ELSE 0 end) as template_temp 
FROM template 
WHERE '2013-08-21' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

and i get this error : Subquery returns more than 1 row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is obvious because one of our sub query returns more than one row. You can use `LIMIT 1` on each sub query. However, if you want to get more than one row you can use `UNION` like this

```
SELECT template_temp FROM
(
    (SELECT applyto_temp AS template_temp, 1 AS temp_applyto FROM individu WHERE applyto_individu = $user) UNION
    (SELECT a.applyto_temp AS template_temp, 2 AS temp_applyto FROM branch a, staff b WHERE a.applyto_branch=b.branch AND b.id=$user) UNION
    (SELECT a.applyto_temp AS template_temp, 3 AS temp_applyto FROM dept a, staff b WHERE a.applyto_dept=b.dept AND b.id=$user) UNION
    (SELECT a.applyto_temp AS template_temp, 4 AS temp_applyto FROM `position` a, staff b WHERE a.applyto_position=b.`position` AND b.id=$user)
) AS combine INNER JOIN template
ON (combine.temp_applyto = template.temp_applyto)
WHERE '2013-08-21' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

Comment: thanks invisal and Aleks G for the quick reply... i already test your query but invisal query return 0 row and yes i want to return more then 1 row. is there any other solution?

Comment: Return 0 query without any error? Is it possible for you to build your sample database in this website http://sqlfiddle.com/. It is a lot easier for us to test and find the solution.

Comment: sorry invisal.. its working.. my bad. but i want to ask u something.. what about if i have temp_applyto (table template)=0 that apply to all user and doesn't have table like the others. i try to put (SELECT temp_id AS template_temp, 0 AS temp_applyto FROM template).. can i do that?

Comment: invisal, how if temp_applyto=0 for all user and its dont store to any table like the others?

Answer (score 0):

The error is rather self-explanatory: one of your subqueries returns more than one row.  There are several ways to solve your problem.  One simple one would be to add `LIMIT 1` to each of the subselects.  Alternatively, you can sub-select the number of rows - and then compare the result to 0:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN temp_applyto=1 
    THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM individu 
          WHERE applyto_individu=$user)
    WHEN temp_applyto=2 
    THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM branch a, staff b 
          WHERE >a.applyto_branch=b.branch AND b.id=$user)
    WHEN temp_applyto=3 
    THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dept a, staff b 
          WHERE >a.applyto_dept=b.dept AND b.id=$user) 
    WHEN temp_applyto=4
    THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM position a, staff b 
          WHERE a.applyto_position=b.position AND b.id=$user)
    ELSE 0 END) as template_temp 
FROM template
WHERE '2013-08-21' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

This will return you one number - 0 if there are no matches or the number of matches if there are any.

Comment: tq Aleks G.. i'll try later